# windows batch script .bat for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm having a hard time understanding what the below code is doing.

```
for /f "delims=:. tokens=1-4" %%t in ("%TIME: =0%") do (
        set FILENAME=event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w
    )
```

I know it's a `for loop`.

`/f` => I imagine this means for each file in a directory.

`delims=:.` =>  I understand this means use `:` as a delimiter. Not sure what `.` means.

`tokens=1-4` => It seems this is grabbing the first four files in a directory

`%%t` => Not sure what this means

`("%TIME: =0%")` => No idea what this means

So for each file matching the above criteria, it does this:

`set FILENAME=event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w` => Which i presume means rename each file.

What i also dont understand is:

event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w =>  I know "event" is part of the name.  But what does `%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w` mean?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. Use [ss64.com/nt](http://ss64.com/nt) as resource to lookup all the commands used or enter in cmd window `help` followed by the command you are looking for.

Comment: use `help for` in a cmd window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a for loop. *correct*

/f => I imagine this means for each file in a directory. *Not quite. `/f` is a kind of "multi-purpose switch" - see `for /?` for details*

delims=:. => I understand this means use : as a delimiter. Not sure what . means. *it defines both `:` and `.` as delimiters - the string will be split at each of those chars*

tokens=1-4 => It seems this is grabbing the first four files in a directory *no, it grabs the first four tokens of the string (delimited by the defined delims)*

*The `for /f` loop splits it into four tokens: `%%t` is the first, then down the alphabet: `%%u`, `%%v` and `%%w`*

%%t => Not sure what this means *this is the variable name for the (first) token*

("%TIME: =0%") => No idea what this means *it replaces each space in the string with a zero - see `set /?` for details*

So for each file matching the above criteria, it does this: *nothing to do with files here*

set FILENAME=event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w => Which i presume means rename each file. *no, it creates a variable named `filename` by concatenating several strings*

**What it really does:**

`%time%` is an internal variable and contains the current time. (Attention, the time format depends on local settings - the code fragment assumes a format of `9:11:22.33` (there is a leading space before the `9`)).
`%time: =0%` replaces the space, resulting in `09:11:22.33`.

The `for /f` loop splits this string into four tokens (`%%t`=`09`, `%%u`=`11`, `%%v`=`22` and `%%w`=`33`.

`%5` is the fifth parameter to the batch file (let's assume, it is `whatever`)

`set FILENAME=event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w` sets the `filename` variable to `event-whatever-09112233`

I recommend to bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) and visit it on a regular basis. You can also get help with every command by executing it with the `/?` switch (`for /?`, `set /?` etc.)

Comment: what im having trouble with is what exactly is the for loop looping through? What string?

Comment: `09:11:22.33`  .